# SVG - resize tspan to fill all available space

Tags: string, svg

I have `tspan` element with some text in it. I specified some `font-size` for it as well. In addition I have parent's box size, i.e. width and height. So now I'd like my text to fit the box with the specified width and height.

One of the options I have is manually calculate string `width` and `height` (but it became more complicated in case of different fonts and browsers).

So is there any other way in SVG to resize `tspan` to necessary sizes? Please note that I want text font size to be changed properly, i.e. so text will be displayed in **max** font size and any single char from it will be visible.

Comment: I've not tried it, but I wonder if Raphael can give you a calculated width and height, given the `id` of a `tspan`? You could then use this to bump up the `font-size` incrementally until your preferred size is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've came up with the following solution - have absolutely positioned `div` element outside of visible area. Apply all fonts and other-related styles (except font size) from `tspan` to that `div`, put text into the `div`. Next try different sizes (you can use binary search for better performance) and measure `div` size. Once max font size found - apply it along with the text to `tspan`.